# JavaScript fillStyle usable with stroke()?

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript, is it possible to use any sort of `fillStyle` in a `stroke()`?
Here is my code:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var first = text.getContext("2d");
first.font = "100px SimLLHP";
first.strokeStyle = "blue";
first.strokeText("T1",100,100);
var last = text.getContext("2d");
last.font = "100px SimLLHP";
last.strokeStyle = "blue";
last.strokeText("T2",110,180)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you specify what you want to achieve: what you observe now with the program you show here and what you you would like to observe instead.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. `stroke` and `fill` both have their own properties and methods in order to draw on the HTML5 Canvas. `stroke` is for contours, such as outlines or lines. And `fill` for solid shapes. Hence `fillStyle` is only for filling, and `strokeStyle` for strokes. There isn't a reason to mix them.

So if you want to have filled in text then we just use `fillStyle` with `fillText`.

```
var last = text.getContext("2d");
last.font = "100px SimLLHP";
last.fillStyle = "blue";
last.fillText("T2",110,180)
```

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/vvzV4/)

Say we want it to be filled and have an outline, then we do `fill` first then `stroke`.

```
// I hope you don't mind me using "ctx", it's the most common.
var ctx = text.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "100px SimLLHP";
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillText("T2",10,100);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeText("T2",10,100);
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vvzV4/1/)